# Adding the same anonymous object to separate collections

Tags: java

Considering the following code

```
ArrayList<SomeObject> One = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();
ArrayList<SomeObject> Two = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();

One.add(new SomeObject());
```

Is it possible to also add this object to the second list without creating it non-anonymously?

Comment: Write a function called addToLists which takes a list of lists and an object, and adds the object to each list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to make a non-anonymous reference to the object, you have 2 ways of obtaining it.

1. Get it from the list (Good if you have an identifier, and need only ONE object)
2. Add all objects from one list to another (Good if you want ALL objects in the list)

For the first method, you can loop through the list until you have hit some sort of identifier for the object (for example an id), and then add it to the second list. If you do not have a distinct identifier, this will not work will as you cannot tell whether or not you are adding the correct item. An example of this method would be:

```
for(Object o : one){
    if(o.getId() == someId){
        two.add(o);
    }
}
```

As for the second method, the `Collections` in `Java` contain `addAll()` methods. This would work by taking all contents of one collection, and adding them to the other collection. This would only work well if you had a list of 1 item or you need all items from one list to another. You couldn't specifically target a single object using this method. An example of how to do this would be:

```
one.addAll(two);
```

Alternatively, if you KNOW that the item you wish to copy will ALWAYS be the first item in the list you are taking it from, you could copy the item at index 0 from one list to the other. This only works if you are CERTAIN that it will always be at index 0, so it is ill advised to use. An example of this would be:

```
two.add(one.get(0));
```

With how compilers work for `Java`, you do not need to worry about creating variables anonymously, as most compiles will translate an anonymous reference to a non-anonymous reference, at least from my experience.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<SomeObject> One = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();
ArrayList<SomeObject> Two = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();

SomeObject myNewObj = new SomeObject();
One.add(myNewObj);
Two.add(myNewObj);
```

Comment: I'm trying to tackle a problem where it would be extremely helpful if a subset of anonymous objects could be added to two lists at once. In this situation it's not practical to name each one.

Comment: what do you mean by "anonymous objects"?

Comment: @BeepBeep: Why isn't it practical to name each one?  It sounds like your code ought to be redesigned so it _is_.

Comment: Objects without a name to reference them which would otherwise fall out of scope if they weren't retained by a list, in the context of my application.

Comment: @Louis I'm creating particle objects which are than handled by another part of my program. There's a small number of them that I would also like to be able to access in a second collection. I don't understand the downvotes, even if my question is bad programming practice surely it should be answered as a hypothetical question?

Comment: @LouisWasserman You are right though, this does point to a flaw in my code and I should probably reevaluate it. Unfortunately this would be a lot of work.

Comment: Perhaps the example you gave above is too simplistic to demonstrate the problem to us. If you give us a more detailed example, maybe we can further help

Comment: Can the objects be created in a loop or some other way that allows you to avoid creating a new variable name for each object?

Comment: I think that will end up being the solution. Some of the objects need specific paramaters which is why I wasn't able to incorporate a loop, but I'll try and work around it. I'm marking an answer as helpful, I think I posed my question too simply and without enough context. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Could always be cheeky and do..

```
secondList.add(firstList.get(0));
```

But that would just be a horrible bit of code. Maintain a reference, or better still..ask yourself why your design needs the same object in two lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can always `get` it from the first list, then immediately to the second list.

```
Two.add(One.get(0));
```

However, this relies on it always being first in the first list.

There is nothing wrong with creating a variable and giving it a name.

```
ArrayList<SomeObject> one = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();
ArrayList<SomeObject> two = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();

SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();
one.add(someObject);
two.add(someObject);
```

It's more readable.

Also, by standard naming convention, variables names in Java should start with lowercase letters, e.g. `one` and `two`.

Answer (score 0):

If one of these shared objects become null, it should be removed from all lists it resides.

Producers:

```
p1.add(work_list);
p1.add(work_list2);
p2.add(work_list);
p3.add(work_list);
p4.add(work_list);
p5.add(work_list);
p6.add(work_list);
p7.add(work_list);
```

Consumers:

```
c[0].add(work_done);
c[1].add(work_done2);
c[2].add(work_done);
```